# Object reference and assigning new class with it

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

Trying to pass the object reference and set it in the new script/class. 
Player.cs

How do i go about referencing correctly, and assigning

Comment: You don't need to instantiate `Player` when you want to just throw it away in the next line. `Player = NewPlayer;`

Comment: so according to the photo, `Player.Achievement` is not instantiated. instantiate `Player.Achievement` and you're good to go

Comment: That was an error, was testing stuff. here is where it all goes wrong https://puu.sh/AQune/9ff16e6b16.png

AchievementList is a Unity text field

Comment: select the game object with `PanelUpdate` attached to it. then find `AchievementList` in inspector. its value should be <none>. drag and drop the UI text on it

Comment: found yet another error: `public PanelUpdate(PlayerDetails NewPlayer)
{
    PlayerDetails Player = new PlayerDetails();
   Player = NewPlayer;
}` is wrong. constructors are not functional in monobehaviour

Comment: Could you edit your question and add some more code .

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is one of those nasty instances of a NullPointer exception being able to refer to multiple problems. It only gives you the line number, but it doesn't give you which reference in that line was null. `NewPlayer` isn't null, `AchievementList` is. You need to initialize that value either earlier in the `ShowUI` method or in the PanelUpdate constructor.

P.S. I HATE the non-specificity of null reference exceptions; very frustrating.

Comment: So i made the constructor and passed PlayerDetails to it and assigned it to a new one, still not sure, but its still showing 'this' as null https://puu.sh/AQtUk/b58c3360dc.png

Comment: Yes, you can't pass a reference of an object until the constructor has finished. You can use `this` to assign values (aka this.Player =...), but you can't assign values to `this` (aka myVar=this). I think this representation is just how the debugger shows it.

Comment: But I think you might have missed what I was trying to point out. You need to initialize `AchievementList` in the constructor, not `NewPlayer` or `Player`. `AchievementList` is the value that is null.

Comment: Cant initialize achievement list. its a unity text field, trying to sets the same error anyways

Comment: @user3072143 i think he meant NewPlayer.Achievement

Comment: https://puu.sh/AQuvK/13ecfb1b7a.png Did so, same problem

Answer (score 0):

Your PlayerDetails object has a null property in it. Check the properties on the NewPlayer object in debug mode and you will see this.

Even if you use a new Constructor on it it doesn't mean the property will be given a value unless it's specifically given one within the constructor.

You also need to show the code for the PlayerDetails class to give us a better idea.

Also:

```
PlayerDetails Player = new PlayerDetails(); // Assigning a new value here means nothing
Player = NewPlayer;
```

You're creating a new PlayerDetails object on line #1 but then assign it a different value on line #2.

```
PlayerDetails Player = NewPlayer;
```

Is fine.